# Is there any way to break long command into multi lines in GitlabCI

Tags: gitlab

I have a very long command in `.gitlab-ci.yml` file to ssh to jump host then use `rsync` to sync files from my repo to destination host (it does not have public ip so I need to access it via jump host).

Here is my `.gitlab-ci`:

```
image: ubuntu
before_script:
  - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client rsync git -y )'
  - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
  - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
  - echo -e "$PRIVATE_KEY" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  - chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'


SSH:
  tags:
    - mytag
  script:
  - ssh ubuntu@host "which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client rsync git -y ) && ssh ubuntu@192.168.1.2 "mkdir -p /home/ubuntu/test" && rsync /home/ubuntu/test/.gitlab-ci.yml ubuntu@192.168.1.2:/home/ubuntu/test/.gitlab-ci.yml"
```

The command here is so long:

```
 ssh ubuntu@host "which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client rsync git -y ) && ssh ubuntu@192.168.1.2 "mkdir -p /home/ubuntu/test" && rsync /home/ubuntu/test/.gitlab-ci.yml ubuntu@192.168.1.2:/home/ubuntu/test/.gitlab-ci.yml"
```

Let me explain it:

- First it `ssh` to `host` then install `rsync` if it does not exist, then it ssh to my private server `192.168.1.2` and then sync my file named `.gitlab-ci.yml` (the file from my repo in my Gitlab server) to folder `test`

I just wonder if there is any way to break long command above to multi lines command?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since `.gitlab-ci.yml` is a `Yaml` file, then just use it's syntax.

For example, you may use `>`:

```yaml
image: ubuntu
before_script:
  - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client rsync git -y )'
  - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
  - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
  - echo -e "$PRIVATE_KEY" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  - chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'


SSH:
  tags:
    - mytag
  script: > 
  - ssh ubuntu@host "which ssh-agent || 
    ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client rsync git -y ) && 
    ssh ubuntu@192.168.1.2 "mkdir -p /home/ubuntu/test" && 
    rsync /home/ubuntu/test/.gitlab-ci.yml ubuntu@192.168.1.2:/home/ubuntu/test/.gitlab-ci.yml"
```

## Sample usage of `yaml` multilines

There is a great resource about `yaml` multilines: [YAML Multiline Strings](https://yaml-multiline.info/)
Also, there is a [great SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21699210/5720818) about `yaml` multilines.

So let's speculate about pipeline based on these materials.
Since we have specific context (script for `Gitlab CI`) then we don't need all of theese 63 cases:

```
                      >     |            "     '     >-     >+     |-     |+
-------------------------|------|-----|-----|-----|------|------|------|------  
Trailing spaces   | Kept | Kept |     |     |     | Kept | Kept | Kept | Kept
Single newline => | _    | \n   | _   | _   | _   | _    |  _   | \n   | \n
Double newline => | \n   | \n\n | \n  | \n  | \n  | \n   |  \n  | \n\n | \n\n
Final newline  => | \n   | \n   |     |     |     |      |  \n  |      | \n
Final dbl nl's => |      |      |     |     |     |      | Kept |      | Kept  
In-line newlines  | No   | No   | No  | \n  | No  | No   | No   | No   | No
Spaceless newlines| No   | No   | No  | \   | No  | No   | No   | No   | No 
Single quote      | '    | '    | '   | '   | ''  | '    | '    | '    | '
Double quote      | "    | "    | "   | \"  | "   | "    | "    | "    | "
Backslash         | \    | \    | \   | \\  | \   | \    | \    | \    | \
" #", ": "        | Ok   | Ok   | No  | Ok  | Ok  | Ok   | Ok   | Ok   | Ok
Can start on same | No   | No   | Yes | Yes | Yes | No   | No   | No   | No
line as key       |
```

Assumptions are:

- we don't need trailing spaces at all
- we don't need final newlines at all
- we'll try to avoid quote escaping mess
- Backslash is intended to combine multi-line scripts
- almost doesn't matter how many spaces before the script

P.s. I'd suggest to lint your `.gitlab-ci.yml` using GitLab UI: [Validate GitLab CI/CD configuration](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/lint.html)

Comment: Awesome, let me try this! Thank you a lot!

Comment: My pipeline says: Job succeeded, thanks you for your help!